# Removing component with settimeout - React Class Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a notification component, which when rendered, I remove it with some delay.

The problem is that when I try to use clearTimeout to cancel the removal, it doesn't. Look

```
class Notify extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.class = 'check'
        this.state = {load:LineNotify[this.class].anime}
        this._delay()
        this.timerS = null
        this.box = BoxNotify[this.class]
        this.icon = IconNotify[this.class]
    }
    remove=()=>{
        // console.log('removed')
        unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('notify'))        
    }

    _delay=()=>{
        this.timerS = setTimeout(this.remove,2400)
    }

    stop=()=>{
        clearTimeout(this.timerS)
        this.setState({load:LineNotify[this.class].line})
    }
    start=()=>{
        this.timerS = setTimeout(this.remove,2400)
        this.setState({load:LineNotify[this.class].anime})
    }
```

I have functions to control component removal, they must be called with cursor input, ie if user hovers, I should use clearTimeout to cancel removal  ("start,stop")

```
remove=()=>{
    console.log('removed')
    // unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('notify'))        
}
```

When I don't use unmountComponentAtNode, using clearTimeout works as expected, but when using unmountComponentAtNode, clearTimeout is ignored and the component is removed anyway

Comment: Try not to manipulate the DOM directly, let React do it for you. You can use States.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Maybe somehow the timer ID returned by setTimeout is getting lost.

```
class Notify extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.class = 'check'
        this.state = {load:LineNotify[this.class].anime}
        this.timerS = this.timer()
        this.box = BoxNotify[this.class]
        this.icon = IconNotify[this.class]
    }

    timer=()=>setTimeout(()=>{
        document.getElementById('notify').remove()
    },2400)

    stop=()=>{
        clearTimeout(this.timerS)
        this.setState({load:LineNotify[this.class].line})
    }
    start=()=>{
        this.timerS = this.timer()
        this.setState({load:LineNotify[this.class].anime})
    }
```